# No In App Purchase Section in View Details

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have submitted my application for review. They have rejected my application saying that , i have failed to submit the In-App Purchase products along with the binary.

[image]

Now i have registered the products in iTunes Connect, i am trying to submit the In-App Purchase products by adding them in the Application "View Details" page.

But, here comes the actual problem.

"In-App Purchase" section is not there.

[image]

How can i submit the products now?

Anyone faced similar kind of issue?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Are you in the provisioning portal or iTC? Or, probably more helpful, show us a screenshot of where you think you should see it and don't